# Why “offer.alibaba” opens all the time

Tags: internet, browser, website

Whenever I open a website and click a link inside it, it redirects me to some URLs and then finally it reaches to the link "offer.alibaba.com" and showing me some offer. I just googled it but the results are offering virus scan software for download and other stuff like that. I want to know what is that and from where it came into my laptop?

Answer (score -1):

I found information on where it comes from. I have not included the link to the website where I found this information, as that website may download malicious software onto your computer. The information you're looking for is this:

> Adware.Alibaba.3 is a malicious Trojan infection that can sneak into computers 
>       secretly via the Internet. Cyber hackers who design this Trojan horse virus can
>       implant this Trojan into many websites and make it spreads widely all around the
>       world. With a small size, this Trojan can easily be saved on the servers of web pages,
>       which can make the infection infiltrate into innocent computers which are visiting
>       those infected websites. Except that, this Trojan can be embedded into other free
>       programs. Once people download those infected software from some unreliable resources,
>       after install the infected application on their computers, this Trojan can hack into
>       those computers at the same time without any notification. Also, cyber hackers can add
>       this Trojan as a attachment in a E-mail, and forge the title of the E-mail that make
>       computer users who receive this spam E-mail comes from a legit place. People can be
>       easily cheated by the title and lured to open the attachment which actually is the
>       executable file of the Trojan.
>
> The Adware.Alibaba.3 virus is very tricky, and it takes use of system leaks to drop
>       harmful threats to the computer. Also, it may enable some unwanted plug-ins and
>       extensions to be installed in the contaminated system secretly. Consequently, the CPU
>       usage of the computer will be taken up greatly. Moreover, the Trojan infection makes
>       great chaos during users Internet browsing activities. Users will be very annoyed
>       by being redirected to other harmful web pages every time you click on web links and
>       search for favorite content. You just find that computer settings like desktop image
>       and browser homepage are changed casually. Actually, the Trojan infection may enable
>       remote hackers to visit the computer without any consent in order to collect vital
>       information. Thus, a prompt manual removal process should be carried out to deal with
>       the risky Adware.Alibaba.3 virus immediately.

I would recommend getting something other than just an AV program, like Malwarebytes, which, is not AV but anti-malware, and runs in conjunction with every AV program I've ever used. (I've used a lot.)

Comment: That link you posted is quite spammy, and it's usually the kind of website you should avoid. It'll download some fishy adware removal tool. I would really consider removing your answer or at least that specific link.

Comment: I did not intend to have anyone download anything from that! My apologies! Editing now! Thank you @slhch